# Is GHC porting to FreeBSD stopped?

Tags: freebsd, port, maintenance, ghc, haskell

I'm playing with GHC package on FreeBSD 8.1.
I installed GHC with `pkg_add -r ghc`. But it was not worked well. I tried some more but I realized the installed GHC version is just 6.10.x. This version is came out in 2009.
Current recent version is 7.x, and last stable version shipped in Haskell Platform was 6.12.x.

Is Haskell porting stopped? Or am I using wrong package? Please let me know!

Comment: If your system is 8.1-RELEASE (and not 8.1-STABLE), then the ports installed by pkg_add will track the builds from the release date (early last year). If it's STABLE it will track the latest ported version. Keep in mind the porting is usually done by FreeBSD Volunteers, not GHC (or others), so it lags a bit behind at times.

Comment: @Chris Oh thanks. I'll take care. And where can I get STABLE version? There is only RELEASE version on FreeBSD website.

Comment: @Eonil, the STABLE versions you have to build from source or use the `freebsd-update` command.

Comment: @Chris It's totally new information to me! I didn't even know about existence of STABLE version! Does STABLE version can offer more recent ports?

Comment: Yep, STABLE will track the Latest port directory, which it usually a month old or less. It makes thing a touch more complicated as new ports can have new dependencies. It's not terrible, but people who want to just 'keep it simple' can stick with the RELEASE version.

Comment: @Chris Oh new dependency... It's bad news. I'll be one of the 'keep it simple' guys. Because that's the reason of why I chosen FreeBSD instead of Linux :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use can use [Latest official GHC](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/download_ghc_6_12_3#freebsd). GHC 6.12 has not yet been add in official FreeBSD ports.